# WPF Dashboard and Widgets

Tags: wpf, dashboard

Hi I would like to write some kind of dashboard. You should be able to drag widgets on the dashboard from some source. The layout of the widgets should be free (first Canvas, later some own Panel).

My questions:

- Do you have any hints for information about this kind of controls for me?
- Is it a good idea to use Selector as BaseClass or should inherit from Control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a `BaseClass` for all widgets, and then build a `ViewModel` that inherits from that `BaseClass` for each Widget, along with a `View` to go with that `ViewModel`

After that, I would have something like `ObservableCollection<WidgetBaseViewModel> OpenWidgets` in the main application `ViewModel`, and bind it to an `ItemsControl`.

The `ItemsControl` would have it's `ItemsPanelTemplate` set to a `Canvas`, and each `WidgetBaseViewModel` would contain a `Top`, `Left`, `Height`, and `Width` property.

The actual UI to display each Widget with would be based on a `DataTemplate`, and could be anything you want, although a `UserControl` would be easiest

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding OpenWidgets}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:WidgetAViewModel}">
            <local:WidgetAView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:WidgetBViewModel}">
            <local:WidgetBView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Canvas ... />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Also, you'll need to bind your `Canvas.Top`/`Canvas.Left` on the `ItemContainerStyle` instead of on the actual `ItemTemplate` to get it to display correctly in the canvas.